# How to setting landscape in laravel-dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, dompdf

I get reference from here : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

My controller code is like this :

```
public function listdata()
{
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('pdf.test_pdf');
    return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

I try setting landscape in `\config\dompdf` like this :

```
'show_warnings' => false,   // Throw an Exception on warnings from dompdf
'orientation' => 'landscape',
```

But, it's not working. The result is still portrait

Is there any people who can help me?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the option `setPaper` option:

```
public function listdata()
{
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.test_pdf')->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('test_pdf.pdf');
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: @samueltoh so why are you commenting on older posts? If a user knows the answer he will post it... please don't spam on other post because this is not the same issue.